# Selenium-Grid,I want to reduce the browser start-time

Tags: java, selenium, apache-commons, selenium-grid

Question description:

The steps are as following:

1.I use selenium-server-standalone-2.49.1.jar to start hub and node.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.49.1.jar -role hub -maxSession 40
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.49.1.jar -role node  -hub    http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,version=2.8,maxInstances=40,platform=LINUX
```

2.use java to code :

```
String serverUrl=  "http://192.168.179.142:4444/wd/hub ";
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capability.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(serverUrl), capability);webDriver.get("http://www.google.cn")
```

now My question is:
  when the WebDriver was instanced,it will spend 3 seconds,For me,this 3 seconds is to long.I want to reduce this time ,about in 1 seconds.how can i do?
  I guess, whether I can use apache common-pool2, use it to create a WebDriver pool.

Comment: Your serverUrl is pointing at a remote machine. So maybe there is network latency that is adding to the time. What happens when you run this against the local grid [ i.e., your test and your grid setup are both on the same machine ] ? Do you see the same time being taken ?

Comment: With respect to setting up a webdriver pool, there are many things that you would need to consider viz., dealing with the browser cleanup at grid side due to browser idleness, ensuring that tests cleanup cookies information on the browser after it runs to completion because now you aren't going to be closing browsers, but just sharing them. So I dont think that taking the webdriver pool approach is a good idea

Comment: Thank you for your help @ Krishnan Mahadevan